# Automatically closing Drawer when view width is decreasing

Tags: react-native, material-ui

I'm trying to make a view like Firebase's console with React and material-ui.

How can I build a Drawer that will automatically close when view(browser) width is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy, you can hook up the listener on resize event on your react class:

```js
var RootPage = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <Drawer refs={'drawer'} />;
    },
    
    // we trigger our drawer here
    componentWillUpdate: function(nextProp, nextState) {
      if(nextState.width < this.state.width) {
        this.refs.drawer.open = false;
      }
    },
    
    windowOnResize: function() {
      var width = $(window).width();
      this.setState({ width: width });
    },
    
    componentWillMount: function() {
      this.windowOnResize();
    },
    
    componentDidMount: function() {
      window.addEventListener("resize", this.windowOnResize);
    },
    
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", this.windowOnResize);
    }
});
```